# XSLT duplicating dependent data from XML

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-grouping, workday-api

I am facing issue with the xslt transformation from xml.

Xml: The node "<wd:GPAR_LRV_Dependents_group>" is repeated 12 times in xml and the business object to extract dependent information is "worker". So for every report entry it is repeated.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F1roJ.png)

Xslt: I have used "for-each" and that's the reason data is duplicated

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t8HOQ.png)

Output: This is how the output looks, the data is duplicated. Ideally dependent one, two and three should populate only once.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/02333.png)

How can I restrict the data from duplicating? how can I do that in Xslt?

Any suggestion how to get this or manage this via calc field?

Thanks!

I have tried for-each-group with dependent ID and I tried position(), but that did not solve it.

Comment: Please make sure you add and enter all code samples inline, as text, not (only) as images. If you have written XSLT 2 or 3 code using `xsl:for-each-group` then show minimal but complete samples of XML input, XSLT code, output you want and output or error you get, to allow others to easily reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

We can't see the rest of your XSLT or XML, so we can't see if you are doing anything to output the record multiple times.

You should be able to filter down to Dependent Events and Successfully Completed by adding a filter on the secondary business object.

If you update your pictures to include everything, you may get more specific help.

-Wyatt